# Greasemonkey script compiler is showing an error

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have script  like this

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          messi
// @namespace     http://messi.com
// @description   example script to alert "barcelona" on userscripts page
// @include       http://userscripts.org/*

// ==/UserScript==

alert('barcelona');
```

this script works with Greasemonkey.

I compiled this script using this link:
https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php.

After compilation I added add-on to Firefox, now it showing:

> **Error: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype objec**  error .

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The user script compiler wasn't updated in quite some time and the output add-ons it produces stopped working in recent Firefox versions IIRC.

If you want to create Firefox add-ons from userscripts, you should consider using the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) and making your user-script a [page mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html). That is what the addons.mozilla.org editor team is recommending, anyway.

There are other alternatives, such as [Scriptify](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/scriptify/).